# SQL query to find an output table

Tags: sql

I have three dimension tables and a fact table and i need to write a query in such way that i join all the dimension columns with fact table to find out top 10 ATMs where most transactions are in the ’inactive’ state.I try the query with cartesian join but i dont know if this is the right way to join the tables.

```
select a.atm_number,a.atm_manufacturer,b.location,count(c.trans_id) as total_transaction_count,count(c.atm_status) as inactive_count
from dimen_atm a,dimen_location b,fact_atm_trans c
where a.atm_id = c.atm_id and b.location = c.location 
order by inactive_count desc limit 10;
```

dimen_card_type

```
+------------+---------+
|card_type_id|card_type|
+------------+---------+
|           1|   CIRRUS|
|           2|  Dankort|
```

dimen_atm

```
+------+----------+----------------+---------------+
|atm_id|atm_number|atm_manufacturer|atm_location_id|
+------+----------+----------------+---------------+
|     1|         1|             NCR|             16|
|     2|         2|             NCR|             64|
+------+----------+----------------+---------------+
```

dimen_location

```
+-----------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+-------+------+------+
|location_id|            location|      streetname|street_number|zipcode|   lat|   lon|
+-----------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+-------+------+------+
|          1|Intern  KÃƒÂ¸benhavn|RÃƒÂ¥dhuspladsen|           75|   1550|55.676|12.571|
|          2|        KÃƒÂ¸benhavn|  Regnbuepladsen|            5|   1550|55.676|12.571|
+-----------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+-------+------+------+
```

fact_atm_trans

```
+--------+------+--------------+-------+------------+----------+--------+----------+------------------+------------+------------+-------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+
|trans_id|atm_id|weather_loc_id|date_id|card_type_id|atm_status|currency|   service|transaction_amount|message_code|message_text|rain_3h|clouds_all|weather_id|weather_main|weather_description|
+--------+------+--------------+-------+------------+----------+--------+----------+------------------+------------+------------+-------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+
|       1|     1|            16|   5229|           3|    Active|     DKK|Withdrawal|              5980|        null|        null|    0.0|        80|       803|      Clouds|     broken cloudsr|
|       2|     1|            16|   4090|          10|    Active|     DKK|Withdrawal|              3992|        null|        null|    0.0|        32|       802|      Clouds|  scattered cloudsr|
+--------+------+--------------+-------+------------+----------+--------+----------+------------------+------------+-----------
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i am using redshift